# CSS :not operator for parent

Tags: css, sass

```
<input type="checkbox" >

<aup-switch>
    <input type="checkbox" >
</aup-switch>
```

I have a css style for `input[type="checkbox"]`, but I don't want it to be applied to the input components inside `aup-switch`.
I tried using `not` selector of css, but not working.

```
input[type="checkbox"]:not(aup-switch input[type="checkbox"]) {
    &+label {
        position: relative;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the `<input> ` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: Are you not able to add class on input field

Comment: Sadly, I can't. I can't access the other codebase, so only use not selector to exclude the special items. And the label component is added as a child dynamically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) .CSS can not currently "go back up" the DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `*:not(aup-switch) > input[type='checkbox']` selector instead

```css
*:not(aup-switch) > input[type='checkbox'] {
  -webkit-appearance: unset;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
Normal checkbox: <input type="checkbox" >

<aup-switch>
    aup-switch checkbox: <input type="checkbox" >
</aup-switch>
```

Answer (score 1):

consider code:

```
// scss:
aup-switch {
  input {
   // other styles
   }
}

input {
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 0;
}


// compiled

aup-swich input { // other styles }
input { position: relative; cursor: pointer; padding: 0;}
```